# Maven increase version for submodule only

Tags: maven

The project structure is (all on same version `1.3.0`, which is latest):

```
Parent
-childA
-childB
-childC
```

Parent's pom is:

```
    <groupId>com.dev.bla</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.dev.bla</groupId>
                <artifactId>childA</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
</...>
```

Now, I need to do some changes to `childB` only and not intending to increase `Parent`'s version (No?).

So now my `childB`'s POM looks like:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.dev.bla</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dev.bla</groupId>
    <artifactId>childB</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dev.bla</groupId>
            <artifactId>childA</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Now, when I'm trying to build `Parent` or `childB`, it fails because it figures (as I can see from effective POM) version of `childA` to `1.4.0` which does not exist as `childA` is at its latest `1.3.0`. In short, `{project.version}` in `Parent` translates to `1.4.0` while according to my understanding it should've been translated to `1.3.0` only as `childB` has parent `Parent` with `1.3.0`.

What am  I missing?

Comment: Update the version for all childs and the parent as well...that makes it easier. Use `versions-maven-plugin:set -DnewVersion=1.4.0` starting from root module...

Comment: increase the version of child without increasing version of parent is a bad idea? Should I move versions of parent and all children if there is change in just one child?

Comment: Yes that's the basic idea of a multi module build...have all the same version...make clear everything fit's together...with the new version....For example bug change from `1.3.0` to `1.3.1`...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm sorry but I tend to disagree. What's the point of having a new artifact with a new version if the artifacts' contents are identical? I've always seen aggregator projects (with the Build Reactor) helpful to build all with one `mvn` command and the reactor takes care of the build order if there are inter-dependencies between the sub-projects. Though I agree, if a development is in an early stage, it's likely that all modules change frequently and then it makes sense. Once an application has matured, modules like `api`, for instance, don't change that often.

Comment: But then you have to make sure that version 1.0 of your api works correctly with other versions of the lib ...that means you have to write appropriate integration tests which are slow by definition...and depending on the number of changes your number of tests will increase which means testing takes more and more time....

Comment: @khmarbaise With an API project (ideally containing just interfaces) it`s the other way round: The implementing lib has to work correctly with it. I.e. there is a strict top-down hierarchy from api to lib. But maybe we have just a different understanding of what I call an API project.

Comment: That will not really change a thing so you need to do testing in several implementations ....?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you got a Maven multi-module project. So, when you create the modules (childA & childB) it will automatically take the version from the parent POM.

So,  remove the version tag (**1.4.0**) from the 'childB' POM declaration

```
<groupId>com.dev.bla</groupId>
<artifactId>childB</artifactId>
```

Comment: If the OP prefers to have different versions this doesn't solve his issue. Also "_So, when you create the modules (childA & childB) it will automatically take the version from the parent POM._" is not correct under all cirumstances, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52285587/1744774) (and the OP's final explanations in his question).

Answer (score 0):

It's all about configuration inheritance. That means the following assumptions are not correct:

- > *In short, `{project.version}` in `Parent` translates to `1.4.0`*

  It's **not** in `Parent`, it's in `childB` since that is built and it inherits the `{project.version}` configuration from `Parent` and interpolates it to its own version.
- > *according to my understanding it should've been translated to 1.3.0*

  No, see above.

If you prefer to keep different versions declare the following in `Parent`:

```
<properties>
  <childA.version>1.3.0</childA.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.dev.bla</groupId>
      <artifactId>childA</artifactId>
      <version>${childA.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</...>
```